# JS console.log method prints value twice

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which seems to work basically fine.

The purpose of the code is to print all names starting with an **S** (case sensitive), to console.

```
let names = ['Selma', 'Yirma'];
let sNames = [];
names.forEach( (e)=>{
    if (e.charAt(0) === 'S') {
        sNames.push(e);
    }
        console.log(sNames);
});
```

I used the code in Google chrome console but got "Selma" twice. Why is that? Why not just once?

Comment: Because your `.forEach()` has *two* iterations and "Selma" is added to `sNames` on the first iteration *before* the console log statement? If you only want to see the final result of the loop, move the log statement to after the loop. (As an aside, have you considered `.filter()` instead of `.forEach()` to create your new array? Also, you can say `e[0]` rather than `e.charAt(0)` to get the first character of the string.)

Comment: Wow, didn't think of the concept of putting the `console.log` inside the loop, I missed it and didn't think on a situation each iteration of the loop would effect result by `console.log`. I thank you very much for this enlightenment!!!

Comment: Haven't considered `filter()`. This is part of an exercise. Nice to know `filter()` method for filtering strings we want from an array.

Comment: like this `let sNames = names.filter(s => s[0] === 'S'); console.log(sNames);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing Selma twice because in the first iteration of the loop you push it to sNames, then you log sNames, then you log it again on Yirma. So you see Selma twice. Move your console.log outside of the loop.

```
let names = ['Selma', 'Yirma'];
let sNames = [];
names.forEach( (e)=>{
    if (e.charAt(0) === 'S') {
        sNames.push(e);
    }
});
console.log(sNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your console.log() is inside in for loop, Move console.log() outside of the loop.

```js
    let names = ['Selma', 'Yirma'];
    let sNames = [];
    names.forEach( (e)=>{
        if (e.charAt(0) === 'S') {
            sNames.push(e);
        }
    });
    
    console.log(sNames);
```